# PHP blocking requests (session not being started)

Tags: php, parallel-processing, httprequest

I've tested the script below in Firefox 39.0 and Google Chrome 43.0:

```
<?php
print "Start time: " . date("H:i:s");
sleep(3);
```

I've tested it both locally (under WAMP - Apache/2.4.9, PHP/5.5.12 ) and on a remote host (under Ubuntu, Apache/2.2.17, PHP/5.3.5).

It seems that even though I perform two parallel requests they are not served/processed in parallel (the "second" request is delayed by 3 seconds).

I know that this usually happens when using sessions (due to the session locking mechanism), but given that I'm not using any sessions how come the requests are serialized?

Is there anything else that I could check for?

Note: the value of `session.auto_start` is OFF

Note: I noticed in Firefox, that if I disable the cache (browser's cache) I no longer encounter this. It might be related to [Multiple Ajax requests for same URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189591/multiple-ajax-requests-for-same-url) and to [Chrome treating smart url and causing concurrent requests pend for each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119367/chrome-treating-smart-url-and-causing-concurrent-requests-pend-for-each-other)

Comment: Apache could be imposing a limit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389496/how-do-you-increase-the-max-number-of-concurrent-connections-in-apache

Comment: maybe it's off in the .ini file, but it can easily be started in some OTHER .ini file, .htaccess/httpd.conf php_value directive, or even a session_start() in some file you're including. If you're on 5.4+, check `session_status()`

Comment: @MarcB OP has indicated the exact code which they are testing. `session_start()` seems unlikely but I do agree with the other stuff

Comment: session_status() returns 1 (which means that the session is not started)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: doesn't matter, there's `auto_prepend_file` as well.

Comment: @MarcB Good point, I forgot about that

Comment: There's no AJAX call. I request the file directly from the browser (http://localhost/test.php) in two different tabs.

Comment: @Razvan What happens if you request it in Chrome and FireFox at the same time?

Comment: It works fine. It also works fine if I disable cache on Firefox (using Web Developer toolbar).

Comment: What if you have two different files, test1.php and test2.php, with the same code and request the two files in the same browser?

Comment: It works fine. And it works fine even if I append any different query string to the end of the URL (this is why I think the cause is actually related to the way the two browsers work - see the two links in my question).

Comment: Does Internet Explorer have this issue?

Comment: Strangely, it seems that it doesn't have this issue. In Internet Explorer 9.0 it works fine.

Comment: the page you are loading only has the code you posted above correct?

Comment: Correct, that's the only code from the script.

Comment: This may sound crazy but what if you set `sleep(15);` and check your times, it was taking me about 2-3 seconds to switch tabs and refresh the same page so it seemed like the browser was locking

Comment: If you use Chrome's networking tools then is it downloading fresh or is it doing some "From Cache" process? http://i.stack.imgur.com/DvimR.png If it is from cache then you might have some headers being set incorrectly

Comment: @cmorrissey: The delay is now of 15 seconds between the requests.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: the request is not cached (it's a fresh response).

Comment: I know you are saying its not session locking but have you tried `session_write_close();` ?

Comment: Yes, I even tried session_start(); and then session_write_close(); - but, regardless, I'm almost sure that this was actually related to the browser behavior (as you can see, Internet Explorer, behaves differently - so it is a browser issue).

Comment: **I am able to consistently reproduce this issue in both Chrome and FireFox but IE is not suffering from this.** I used `sleep(10);` to make sure I gave myself adequate time to press refresh in both tabs. Call 1 takes 10 seconds and call 2 takes about 20

Comment: got me then, the onlything I can think of is the max parallel connections http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser

Comment: Using `for($i=0; $i<100000000; ++$i){}` produces the same non-parallel code execution delay in which the second request is waiting for the first one to finish.